# How to convert `Observable` to `ControlEvent`

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

We have a view controller `MainCollectionView` that contains a collection view with a number of cells `FooCell`. And inside each `FooCell`, there is a collection view and a list of cells `BarCell`.

How do I propagate a button tapped event in the `BarCell` to `MainCollectionView`?

This is what we have:

```
class FooCell: ... {

    private let barCellButtonTappedSubject: PublishSubject<Void> = PublishSubject<Void>()
    var barCellButtonTappedObservable: Observable<Void> {
        return barCellButtonTappedSubject.asObserver()
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeue(...)

        if let cell = cell as BarCell {
            cell.button.rx.tap.bind { [weak self] in
                self?.barCellButtonTappedSubject.onNext(())
            }.disposed(by: cell.rx.reusableDisposeBag)
        }

        return cell
    }
}

class MainCollectionView: ... {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeue(...)

        if let cell = cell as FooCell {
            cell.barCellButtonTappedObservable.subscribe { [weak self] in
                // Do other stuff when the button inside bar cell is tapped.
            }.disposed(by: cell.rx.reusableDisposeBag)
        }

        return cell
    }
}
```

This works until I read about [`ControlEvent`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/Documentation/Traits.md#controlevent):

- it never fails
- it won't send any initial value on subscription
- it will Complete sequence on control being deallocated
- it never errors out
- it delivers events on MainScheduler.instance

It looks like it is more appropriate to use `ControlEvent` in the `FooCell`:

```
private let barCellButtonTappedSubject: PublishSubject<Void> = PublishSubject<Void>()
var barCellButtonTappedObservable: Observable<Void> {
    return barCellButtonTappedSubject.asObserver()
}
```

What is the right way to convert this `barCellButtonTappedObservable` to a `ControlEvent`? Or is there other better idea to propagate the `ControlEvent` in the nested cell to the outer view controller?

Comment: Do you care which button was tapped? From what you have above, you don't seem to care which button was tapped in any particular BarCell of a FooCell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I personally prefer using `RxAction` for this kind of stuff, but because you have already declared a `PublishSubject<Void>` in your cell, this is how you can convert a subject to `ControlEvent`

```
controlEvent = ControlEvent<Void>(events: barCellButtonTappedSubject.asObservable())
```

As straight forward as it can get! but if thats all you wanna do, you don't even need a `barCellButtonTappedSubject`

```
controlEvent = ControlEvent<Void>(events: cell.button.rx.tap)
```

In fact, you don't even need to declare a control event :) because `cell.button.rx.tap` itself is a control event :) So if you declare your button as public property in your cell, you can directly access its tap control event in your tableView controller

But personally, I would use `RxAction` rather than declaring a `publishSubject` or `controlEvent` your `FooCell` can ask for action from your `TableViewController`

```
class FooCell: ... {
   var cellTapAction : CocoaAction! = nil

   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeue(...)

        if let cell = cell as BarCell {
            cell.button.rx.action = cellTapAction
        }

        return cell
    }
}
```

Finally your TableViewController/CollectionViewController can pass action as

```
class MainCollectionView: ... {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeue(...)

        if var cell = cell as FooCell {
            cell.cellTapAction = CocoaAction { _ -> Observable<Void> in
               debugPrint("button in cell tapped")
               return Observable.just(())
           }
        }

        return cell
    }
}
```

Only thing you would have to handle is if cellctionView is embedded inside `FooCell` because am passing `action` after `deQueReusableCell` embedded collectionView might load even before action is passed to it so you will have to tweak the logic to either reload the embedded collection view after action passed to `FooCell` or any other workaround which will solve this issue :)

Hope it helps :) I believe using `Action` makes code cleaner and easy to understand.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the `Action` option. It is not something that we used yet but I will keep this in mind.

Comment: @Yuchen Zhong : am glad I could be of help :)

Answer (score 2):

I've never used `Action`s which the other answers have mentioned. I also wonder why you seem to be manually setting up your delegate instead of using RxCocoa to do it. Lastly, it feels like you probably want some way of knowing which button was tapped. I do that in the code below by assigning each Bar cell an ID integer.

```
class BarCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

    func configure(with viewModel: BarViewModel) {
        button.rx.tap
            .map { viewModel.id }
            .bind(to: viewModel.buttonTap)
            .disposed(by: bag)
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        bag = DisposeBag()
    }

    private var bag = DisposeBag()
}

class FooCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    func configure(with viewModel: FooViewModel) {
        viewModel.bars
            .bind(to: collectionView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "Bar", cellType: BarCell.self)) { index, element, cell in
                cell.configure(with: element)
        }
        .disposed(by: bag)
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        bag = DisposeBag()
    }

    private var bag = DisposeBag()
}

class MainCollectionView: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    var viewModel: MainViewModel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let foos = viewModel.foos
            .share()

        let buttonTaps = foos
            .flatMap { Observable.merge($0.map { $0.bars }) }
            .flatMap { Observable.merge($0.map { $0.buttonTap.asObservable() }) }

        buttonTaps
            .subscribe(onNext: {
                print("button \($0) was tapped.")
            })
            .disposed(by: bag)

        foos
            .bind(to: collectionView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "Foo", cellType: FooCell.self)) { index, element, cell in
                cell.configure(with: element)
            }
            .disposed(by: bag)
    }

    private let bag = DisposeBag()
}

struct FooViewModel {
    let bars: Observable<[BarViewModel]>
}

struct BarViewModel {
    let id: Int
    let buttonTap = PublishSubject<Int>()
}

struct MainViewModel {
    let foos: Observable<[FooViewModel]>
}
```

The most interesting bit about the code was the merging up of all the buttonTaps. That was a bit of an adventure to figure out. :-)

Comment: Hey Daniel. I am going with Sandeep's answer for now since it more directly answered the question. But thanks for your answer as well. It is absolutely super inspiring!

Answer (score 0):

I would personally add an action to the button before trying to observe its state like that and handle bubbling up your response from there.

```
class Cell: UICollectionViewCell {
   let button = UIButton(type: .custom)

   func setUpButton() {
      button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Cell.buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
   }

   @IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
      //This runs every time the button is tapped
      //Do something here to notify the parent that your button was selected or handle it in this Cell.
      print(sender.state)
   }
}
```

Comment: Hey, Dare. 1) There is no need to use `@IBAction` since you are adding this action in code. 2) We were using RxSwift, so it is a little bit different in the sense that we already can do what suggest here with `cell.button.rx.tap.bind { [weak self] in ... }`. We are more interesting what is the appropriate way to propagate event from subview out to the main view controllers.